# Using custom wordpress taxonomies for aktivity-streams?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm working on a `WordPress-Website` with a project-custom post type. But the person I am doing this for, has some special, not very uninteresting questions and suggestions. I am not quite sure, weather this is possible, and if it is, than how I should do it:

I created a custom post type: projects. Its custom taxonomies are **"genre"**(tag), and **"customer"**(category). So, if you call a certain customer, you will get the customer-taxonomy page, with a little description of the customer, and all the posts, related to this customer. So far no problem, but he wants the posts to be ordered by genre. Genres means, Webdesign, Corporate Design, Printgraphics, etc..

Is it possible, to list all project-custom posts, related to the custom-taxonomy "customer", and order them by time and the custom-taxonomy "genre"?. It should look like..

> Webdesign:
>
> 2012-05 - Projekt-title 2012-07 - other project title
>
> print:
>
> 2012-04 - print project-title 2012-06 - any project-title

It is important, because He wants the Project-Posts to look like a activity-stream related to the customer, like social media services.

The other Questions is, weather I can somehow combine custom-taxonomies and standart post-taxonomies. The Idea is, to post a standard News-Article, writing about the new project Hes working on. And he wants this article to show up on the related customer page.

Is this possible? And if yes, how should I do it? If it isn't possible, is there any other good solution?

Comment: Actually you need a technique to order posts by more than one taxonomy. Right?

Comment: So you need a technique to group the posts by author, then by genre, and then order them by date.

Comment: I found this for you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37346/group-wp-query-by-category, and it looks like what you need.

Comment: Thanks! This should actually work - Now I just need to find a way, you display related news-posts on the page as well.